# How to embed latex in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, latex

My Wordpress page will contain Mathematical equations. I tried Equation Editor plugin but not satisfactory.
I do not want to use any plugin now and would like to embed Latex code on the pages directly. In the website https://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/, it is showing the following procedure. I tried, but the whole latex code is displaying in the browser.

```
$latex E=mc^2$
$latex i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left|\Psi(t)\right&gt;=H\left|\Psi(t)\right&gt;$
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On default filter WordPress this syntax and also the editor, the TinyMCE. You must enhance the filter and editor to allow the syntax from Latex. Maybe the plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/ helps you easier as custom code to allow it. However see this list before you re-engineer a  solution https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/latex/

Comment: Thanks for the list. I'm using Enable Latex plugin that allows me to write Latex code on my page.